# Node.js and Sendgrid mailer error on res.end

Tags: node.js, heroku, http-headers, express, sendgrid

I'm a bit new to node. I'm using express and the sendgrid api to send an email (collected REST-fully). After sendgrid succeeds or fails, I want to respond with a json object. Here's the sample case:

```
var SendGrid = require('sendgrid-nodejs').SendGrid;
var sendgrid = new SendGrid(user, key);

app.get('/LGP/:email', function (req, res){
    sendgrid.send({
        to: req.params.email,
        from: 'me@example.com',
        subject: 'Hello World',
        text: 'This email sent through SendGrid'
        }, function(success, message) {
            if (!success) {
                console.log(message);
            } else {
                res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
                res.write(JSON.stringify({ result: 'success' }));
                res.end(); //error occurs: "Can't use mutable header APIs after sent."
            }
        }
    );
});
```

On my local server (using foreman), everything works fine. But when I push it to heroku, it gives me this stack trace:

```
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]: http.js:543
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw new Error("Can't use mutable header APIs after sent.");
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Can't use mutable header APIs after sent.
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.getHeader (http.js:543:11)
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/logger.js:229:26
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/logger.js:149:20)
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/app.js:60:13
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sendgrid/lib/sendgrid.js:74:9)
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:81:20)
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:133:23)
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     at CleartextStream.ondata (http.js:1213:22)
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     at CleartextStream._push (tls.js:291:27)
2013-02-27T22:12:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SecurePair._cycle (tls.js:565:20)
2013-02-27T22:12:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-02-27T22:12:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

/app/app.js:60:13 refers to the line with "res.end()". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is likely because res.end() is called more than once.  You should add some logs to check the completion function from sendgrid is not calling you multiple times.  You should also move the `var SendGrid = require(...)` out of the app.get.  The first call is loading the module synchronously.

Comment: Changed the require to be outside and added a console.log() before I writeHead, but I only see the log once, and it still crashes on req.end(). Weird that it only happens when it's on the server and not locally.

Comment: same version of node.js and sendgrid?

Comment: Hmm, not sure how it could be different? From what I understand, don't I just set everything in my package.json? That gets pushed to the server when I commit as well.

Comment: for module yes, but do you specify "*", or exact version for express, sendgrid?  And node version could also matter.  Lots of small changes in node.js http support lately.

Comment: Wow, hit the nail on the head! I wasn't specifying my node version, so it used 0.4 by default. Thanks!

Comment: Also, you should be using the `sendgrid` package, not `sendgrid-nodejs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maximize your chances of your app behaving the same locally and on heroku, you should make sure you specify specific versions for all modules and avoid using `"*"` for the main `dependencies`.

Should also should specify the node version in package.json:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "0.8.20"
}
```

(use whatever version is appropriate).